# How to solve this integral using substitution?

Tags: integration

[Here is the integral question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szsSP.jpg)

> use the substitution $u=5x$ to solve the integral: $$\int\frac{\operatorname d x}{25 x^2+1} = \overline{\underline{\lvert\qquad\rvert}}+c$$

I know it might not be so hard, but I just cannot think of a way to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution? If you have, what happens?

Comment: Did you think about it:What is the derivative of $\arctan u$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int \frac{dx}{25x^2+1} = \frac 1 5 \int \frac{5\,dx}{(5x)^2+1} = \frac 1 5 \int \frac{du}{u^2+1}
$$

Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the integral substitute $u$ for $5x$ to get

$du = 5 \, dx$ and then substitute $u$ and $du$ into the equation to get
$$\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{\operatorname d u}{u^2+1}$$

Then use the identity that the derivative of the inverse tanget function is equal to the integrand.

So the answer is $\frac{1}{5}\arctan(5x)+c$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{\operatorname d x}{25 x^2+1} =\int\frac {1}{u^2+1}\frac{d u}{5}=\frac{1}{5}\int\frac {1}{u^2+1}{d u}=\frac{1}{5}(artan(u)+C_1)= \frac{1}{5}artan(5x)+C $$ where $C=\frac{1}{5}C_1$
Note that: $u=5x \rightarrow du=5dx \rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{5}$ and $25x^2=(5x)^2=u^2$